# iChat disconnecting AirPort connection

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, ichat

Whenever I open iChat in my MacBook, the WiFi connection seems to reset for some reason. I lose the connection and after 10 seconds it reconnects.

Any suggestions?

log file after reproducing problem:

```
25 18:40:55 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 4 (Disassociated due to inactivity).
May 25 18:41:01 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: Auth result for: 00:1e:e5:04:98:0a MAC AUTH succeeded
May 25 18:41:01 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en1
May 25 18:48:13 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::scanDone: Scheduling cache purge timer in 30 seconds.
May 25 18:48:18 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 4 (Disassociated due to inactivity).
May 25 18:48:25 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: Auth result for: 00:1e:e5:04:98:0a MAC AUTH succeeded
May 25 18:48:25 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en1
May 25 18:48:43 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::cachePurge: Firing!
May 25 18:48:43 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::cachePurge: Rescheduling in 11 seconds.
May 25 18:48:54 Alex-Brands-MacBook kernel[0]: IO80211ScanManager::cachePurge: Firing!
```

---

UPDATE:
A firmware update on the router has apparently solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your /var/log/system.log say when this happens?
What version of Mac OS X are you running?

Assuming Snow Leopard:
What does your /var/log/kernel.log say when this happens?
Try running

```
sudo /usr/libexec/airportd debug +AllUserland +AllVendor +AllDriver
```

and then reproduce the problem and see what shows up in your system and kernel logs.

What is the make, model, hardware revision, and firmware version of your Wi-Fi router?
What does the manufacturer's website say is the latest firmware for that particular model and hardware revision?

Try opening up two Terminal windows and running two pings while you reproduce the problem. From one window, ping the private IP address of your Wi-Fi router, and from the other window, ping www.google.com or some other public Internet site.  When the problem reproduces, do *both* pings fail, or just the public one? If the public pings fail, but the pings to your local router don't fail, then you're not really losing your Wi-Fi connection, you're losing your DSL or cable modem connection.

Comment: great advice, hopefully he knows how to do this kind of stuff ;)

Comment: @debug This is Superuser, a site by and for computer geeks, n'est-ce pas? :-) I like to assume the best of my fellow users.

Comment: added the log file info to the top...

Comment: while pinging both the router and google.com, I loose connection to both destination after reproducing the problem... this is weird!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a different chat client such as [Adium](http://adium.im/) or [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/download/mac/).

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem in any way.